# Codeigniter $this->input->post('email', TRUE); not working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
    public function add_new(){ 
            $password = $this->input->post('password', TRUE);
            echo $password;**nothing display**
            $email= $this->input->post('email', TRUE);
            echo $email;**nothing display**
            $salt = $this->password_encrypt->genRndSalt();
            $name = $this->input->post('store_name', TRUE);
            $owner = $this->input->post('auth_person', TRUE);
            $personal_email = $this->input->post('personal_email', TRUE);
            $phone= $this->input->post('phone', TRUE);
            $password = $this->password_encrypt->encryptUserPwd( $this->input->post('password'),$salt);
            echo $password;**display encrypted password**
            $array = array('email'=>$email,'password'=>$password,'salt'=>$salt,'store_name'=>$name,'store_owner'=>$owner ,'personal_email'=>$personal_email,'phone_number'=>$phone);
            $result = $this->register_model->add_user($array);**this will be work;**
            if($result == 1){
                echo 1;

            }else if($result == 0){
                echo 0;
            }
            $this->function1($email); **not get value $email**
    }
```

In  `register_model` I can read variable email.

```
$email=$array['email'];
```

But here `$this->function1($email);` no value for email.

But after **`$password = $this->password_encrypt->encryptUserPwd( $this->input->post('password'),$salt);`** this line **echo $password;** display encrypted password.

And update database properly **`$this->register_model->add_user($array);//this will be work;`**

I want to call function `function1($email);` inside `add_new()` function.

**function1:**

```
public function function1($a){ 
            //$data['email'] =array['email'];
            echo $a;
            $data['email'] = $a;
            $this->load->view('view1',$data);   
            }
```

Comment: can you paste the code for `function1`? How do you know the value for `email` is blank?

Comment: use `print_r($_POST);` to see if the values are appropriately received!

Comment: @ cornelb replace $this->function1($email); with $this->function1("Some text"); then display "Some Text" in view1.

Comment: @Afganistan no change.

Comment: @ cornelb @Afganistan But after '$password = $this->password_encrypt->encryptUserPwd( $this->input->post('password'),$salt);' this line 'echo $password;' display encrypted password.

Comment: your code/problem is not really clear!

Comment: I want call function1($email); but during some problem I can't do it properly. I think it is due to security issues. Because in 2nd line echo $password;**nothing display** but after this $password = $this->password_encrypt->encryptUserPwd( $this->input->post('password'),$salt); 
            echo $password;**display encrypted password**

Comment: when `echo $email;**nothing display**` , how do you want the `$this->function1($email);` work properly ?

Comment: I want know why echo $email; display nothing to solve this problem?  But same time $this->register_model->add_user($array); is working perfectly and update database.

Comment: You should add the html form you are using.